Implementing a progress bar using ambiorix with htmx
I want to implement a progress bar in my application using ambiorix + htmx
This is the logic of the app:
The user clicks a button, this issues a POST request which goes to the end1 endpoint inside here an async process is initialized to update the variable value and a new div tag is shown to the user indicating that the process has initialized.
This div tag should issue a GET request to the getvals endpoint every 2 seconds and return the updated value of the variable value
This is what I tried but the problem is that the value doesn't update it stays at zero, I guess this occurs because of my lack of understanding of async processes so any explanation is appreciated, thanks in advance.

library(future)
library(ambiorix)
library(ipc)
library(htmltools)
plan(multisession)
app <- Ambiorix$new()
value <- 0
q <- queue()
app$get("/", \(req,res){
  tags$button(
    `hx-post` = "/end1",
    "Begin progress"
  ) |> 
    as.character() |> 
    HTML() -> var_1
  res$render("temp.html", list(html_1 = var_1))
})
app$post("/end1", \(req,res){
  futuro_1 <- future({
    for(i in 1:5){
      Sys.sleep(3)
      q$producer$fireEval({
        # print(index)
        value <- index
        value
  
      }, list(index=i))
   }
  })
  futuro_1
  q$consumer$start()
  div(
      `hx-get` = "/getvals",
      `hx-trigger` = "every 2s",
      "Creating Archive"
    ) |> 
    as.character() |> 
    HTML() -> var_2
  res$send(var_2)
})

app$get("/getvals", \(req,res){
  # value
  res$send(as.character(value))
})

app$start()


Here is the HTML code for the temp.html template:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@2.0.3" integrity="sha384-0895/pl2MU10Hqc6jd4RvrthNlDiE9U1tWmX7WRESftEDRosgxNsQG/Ze9YMRzHq" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    [% html_1 %]
</body>
</html>




I ended up opening an issue on GitHub, one of the maintainer was able to produce a solution. See : https://github.com/kennedymwavu/ambiorix-htmx/tree/main/show-progress-async
